# How to make request from php to my server so I can get html content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I m working on open source project (Tao test assestment). In this application you can make some item/question and you can preview that question. With those questions you can build your test, but problem is there is no test preview or print test.

I m trying to find a way to do this. One of my solution was to take all the items from test make a loop and each one of them call in iframe then combine them in one view. That did not work of course.

My question is. Is there some possibility to make request to my own server from php code to get html content and from php code to combine them in one view ?

I saw some functions like @file_get_contents but this returns me false. In php.ini file this are my configuration

allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off

EDIT:
So this is preview of one item/question.

[image]

EDIT:
One test is consisted of items and problem is there is no option to preview them, except click on each one and see them. So i tried with opening each item/question in seperate iframe so i can see them all in one.
[image]

Comment: Any questions, please comment so I can edit my answer, I wish you success on your journey :)

Comment: a client does not have access to PHP code. PHP runs only on your server, and typically outputs HTML, and perhaps javascript, to the browser client. If you need the PHP on your server to put multiple PHP files together, you would typically use something like "include" or "require". You question is unclear and you have shown no code, so I don't thin you will be able to get an answer here.

Comment: Any questions please comment, and if possible please share the piece of code that is failing, and what is the specific error please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If the file is on the same server, i.e. in the same location where PHP is installed:

1 Option:

```
<?php
 $filename = "path_to_file";
 $file = fopen( $filename, "r" );
 
 if( $file == false ) {
    echo ( "Error in opening file" );
    exit();
 }
 
 $filesize = filesize( $filename );
 $filetext = fread( $file, $filesize );
 fclose( $file );
 
 echo ( "File size : $filesize bytes" );
 echo ( "<pre>$filetext</pre>" );
?>
```

2 Option:

```
<?php
include "path_to_file.php"
?>
```

#### If the file is located on another server:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server.com/path_to_file');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// display file
echo $file_contents;
?>
```

Comment: No problem, any questions we are here to help, if this answer was satisfactory, please mark it as accepted.